# Multiple boot windows 8, windows 7 and backtrack

Tags: linux, windows, windows-installer, boot

windows 7 is installed on my laptop now (hp pavilion i7 64 bit). I want to install windows 8, windows 7 and  Linux backtrack. What is the best order of installation to get multiple boot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate all the OS in different drives so that it is easy to repair or delete any OS that malfunctions and damage to one OS does not affects others.

If you have Windows 7 already installed, then you can Installed Windows 8 in Advanced Installation mode and then finally install the Linux Backtrack.

Comment: after I will install backtrack, will automatically the boot show me all previous windows OS?

Comment: I suppose, Linux willload its different Bootloader and hence it would pose some problem, I suggest you should install Linux Backtrack in a VM Instead of clean boot. Or you can have it on a VHD that can boot up automatically on startup.

Comment: If your distributable has GRUB bootloader,then probably it should automatically detect other OSs. I'm not sure about other bootloaders,and which one backtrack uses. In any case,configuring the bootloader wouldn't be a daunting task.